# How to open a single Matlab instance using win32com?

Tags: python, matlab, win32com

I'm using Matlab's COM interface from python like this:

```
import win32com.client
mlab = win32com.client.Dispatch('matlab.application')
mlab.visible = True
print(mlab.Execute("1 + 1"))
```

When I run the code above it correctly prints `ans = 2` but Matlab (Command Window) exits after executing the code. I want to open just one Matlab instance and send commands to it rather than  launching a new Matlab session each time. Is there a way to achieve this?  For the record I'm on Windows using Python 3.4.3 and Matlab R2014A.

Answer (score 2):

It is the destructor of `mlab` which is exiting matlab. Keep this variable and your matlab session will stay open.

I recommend to dispatch only once and use this com instance wherever you need it, this way the garbage collector will do exactly what you want, close matlab as soon as you no longer use it.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you suggest. Can you please elaborate? (maybe showing explicitly how I should modify the code in my question). Thank you!

Comment: You must keep the variable `mlab` somewhere. Once you delete it the object behind get's destroyed and matlab quits.